# WPF Wrappanel in Listbox

Tags: wpf, listview, wrappanel

I want to display several images in a vertical scrolling list, but these images are subdivided into several groups that must be distiguishable by the user. To achive this, I use a ListView which items contain a WrapPanel, which contains the single images:

```
<ListView Name="ListGroups" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <Label Content="{Binding Groupname}" />
                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Images}" >
                    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <WrapPanel  />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                <Image Source="{Binding Thumb}" />
                                <Label Content="{Binding Res}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

What I get is:

[Current result - wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuBnJ.png)

but what I want to achive is:

[Thats what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hhl2J.png)

That is to say I dont want any horizontal Scollbars at all, and the groups clearly must be separated. On the other hand, when sizing the window, the images **within one group** must wrap to fill all available space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just also disable the horizontal ScrollBar of the inner ListBox, and set `Stretch="None"` on the Image element.

```
<ListView ... ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <Label Content="{Binding Groupname}"/>
                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Images}"
                         ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" >
                    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <WrapPanel/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <Image Source="{Binding Thumb}" Stretch="None"/>
                                <Label Content="{Binding Res}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but indeed I  already tried that. What than happens is that all images are stretched horizontally to fill the complete horizontal width of the window. For any reason.

Comment: Then set their Stretch property to None or set a fixed Width. See the edited answer.